# Selecting queries active records codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, foreach

```
$sql = $this->db->select('fname,lname')
            ->where('username', $user)
            ->from('users')
            ->get()
            ->result_array();
 $result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

How do i parse/traverse the results of the query? Based on the user manual/guide provided by ci.

One way of doing so is, using result_array()

```
foreach($result->result_array() as $row)
{
echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
}
```

How would i be able to access those results without having to loop it? 
Or is there any other way of doing the sql part wherein i won't need to use result_array().
I've been having trouble with this matter, since when i try to access the results outside the foreach loop they always go undefined/null. Need some solution/advise.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all query results are returned as an array?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you do SQL queries in CodeIgniter.  You use either `->get()`/`->result_array()` *OR* `->query()`, not both.

```
$result = $this->db
    ->select('fname,lname')
    ->where('username', $user)
    ->from('users')
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

And then:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
}
```